# How to join colums with different field ids?

Tags: sql, oracle

*Hi everyone*. As you can see below I want to count the **c.key_value** with different **c.config_field_id and relation_type_id**.
So I just want to join these two select statements. So as a result there should be shown 3 columns, they are:

| parent_id | count(c.key_value) | count(c.key_value(with another config_field_id, relation_type_id)) |

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

---

```
select parent_id, count(c.key_value) from relation as r 
    left join config_value_number as c on r.child_id = c.key_value 
where c.config_field_id = 100 and relation_type_id = 150
group by parent_id
```

---

```
select parent_id, count(c.key_value) from relation as r 
       left join config_value_number as c on r.child_id = c.key_value 
where c.config_field_id = 101 and relation_type_id = 151 
group by parent_id
```

Comment: In Oracle, using `AS` between a table identifier and an alias is not syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use conditional aggregation for that:

```
select parent_id, 
count(case when c.config_field_id=100 then c.key_value end) as key_value_150, 
count(case when c.config_field_id=101 then c.key_value end) as key_value_151
from relation r 
       left join config_value_number c on r.child_id = c.key_value 
where (c.config_field_id =100 and relation_type_id =150) 
   or (c.config_field_id =101 and relation_type_id =151)
group by parent_id
```

Comment: Will also include mixed combinations, e.g. c.config_field_id = 100 and relation_type_id = 151.

Comment: @jarlh You are absolutely right. Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my answer.

Comment: In Oracle, using `AS` between a table identifier and an alias is not syntactically valid.

Comment: Also, you have mixed up the value for the `config_field_id` and the `relation_type_id` in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: KaziMohammadAliNur Previous worked correctly, but this one is counting only **key_value_150** column. Cause after **where** clause there is **or** operator. So that's why it's not counting both **key_value_150 and key_value_151**

Comment: Do you want to count key_value where relation_type_id =151 and config_field_id =100?

Comment: No actually I want to count key_value where relation_type_id = 150(and)151 and config_field_id = 100(and)101. I meant both of them

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to join those two select statements instead of actual tables as subqueries.

```
SELECT parent_id, left_count, right_count
FROM (select parent_id, count(c.key_value) as left_count 
       from relation as r 
       left join config_value_number as c 
         on r.child_id = c.key_value 
       where c.config_field_id = 100 and relation_type_id = 150 group by parent_id) a
JOIN (select parent_id, count(c.key_value) as right_count 
       from relation as r 
       left join config_value_number as c 
         on r.child_id = c.key_value 
       where c.config_field_id = 101 and relation_type_id = 151 group by parent_id) b
ON a.parent_id = b.parent_id;
```

Comment: In Oracle, using `AS` between a table identifier and an alias is not syntactically valid.